# how to concatenate timestamp in different rows in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a way to concatenate timestamp in two difference row, for an example, I have this table:

[image: Qenter image description here]

I want it to be grouped by weekday and concatenate the min(start_hour) with max(start_hour), to get something like this

[image]

and I'm using this query to retrieve the first image result

Answer (score 0):

The query below should give you what you are looking for provided the information supplied. I made some assumptions. That the '00:00:00' in the start and end hours is not a valid time and can be ignored. If they should be considered valid, then Friday's output would be one entry of '00:00:00' - '11:30:00'.

I created two CTEs, one for the start hours and the other for the end hours where the values are not '00:00:00'. Added a row number to the CTEs so i can match up the day & row_number to get you a set.

```
SELECT day
    ,array_to_string(array_agg(t.shift), ',') shifts
FROM (
    WITH cte_start AS (
            SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY day)
                ,day
                ,start_hour
            FROM test22
            WHERE start_hour <> '00:00:00'::time
            )
        ,cte_stop AS (
            SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY day)
                ,day
                ,stop_hour
            FROM test22
            WHERE stop_hour <> '00:00:00'::time
            )
    SELECT cte_start.day
        ,cte_start.start_hour::varchar || ' - ' || cte_stop.stop_hour::varchar AS shift
    FROM cte_start
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_stop ON cte_start.day = cte_stop.day
        AND cte_start.row_number = cte_stop.row_number
    ) T
GROUP BY T.day
```

-HTH

Comment: Actually, it didn't work the way i wanted, as an example this is day one's data Monday 07:00:00 - 03:00:00,07:00:00 - 23:00:00,13:00:00 - 23:00:00 and what i one to retrieve is only from 11:00 to 02:00

Comment: Ahmed, 11:00 to 02:00 is not in the list of three. Can you please update your question with this scenario. In your question you show that there is a list of start/end times for Friday, but in your comment it looks like you want only one start/end time.

Comment: Sorry ad, data was updated :) 
I will update the images ASAP